# Drag while in background in KineticJs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag, kineticjs

I have two layers generally representing a large background and some content on top of it.
I have made the background draggable but when dragged, it covers the content of the other layer.
Is it possible to keep it in the background while dragging it?

I have tried binding the drag events with .moveToBottom() for the background group (later added to backgroundLayer) like that:

```
groupBackground.on('dragstart',function(){
    groupBackground.moveToBottom();
});
groupBackground.on('dragmove',function(){
     groupBackground.moveToBottom();
});
groupBackground.on('dragend',function(){
     groupBackground.moveToBottom();
});
```

but to no result.

Comment: drag and drop uses a different layer for the performance, I heard.

Comment: I suppose that layer is hidden from me and only used by the system for the dragging. However, do you think there is any way to manipulate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can “draw under” by using the canvas “.globalCompositeOperation”**

This will allow your user to drag the background under the foreground.

And you can apply it to KineticJs like this:

```
layer.getContext().globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
```

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2GFSE/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
var background = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    fill: 'black',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true
});

var foreground = new Kinetic.Ellipse({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 3,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 3,
    radius: {
        x: 50,
        y: 30
    },
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
});

// add the background and foreground to the layer
layer.add(foreground);
layer.draw();
layer.getContext().globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";

layer.add(background);
layer.draw();
```